# Replace character and words

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

How can I replace characters to get a text only with words?

Here's the code:

```
text.replace('/', '');
```

> ley orgánica 4/2013 28 junio reforma consejo general poder judicial modifica ley orgánica 6/1985 1 julio poder judicial

From this text I would like to replace 4/2013 to '' and 6/1985 and the numbers 28 and 1.
Thanks!

Comment: ok so you want to wipe out 4/2013... but what are you wanting for the second date numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, in this limited case:

```
var text = 'ley orgánica 4/2013 28 junio reforma consejo general poder judicial modifica ley orgánica 6/1985 1 julio poder judicial',
    newText = text.replace(/([\/0-9])/g, '');
```

Comment: @MarcOrtiz you should give more information then just "still not working"

Comment: @MarcOrtiz Don't forget that replace, doesn't modify original string. It returns new string with replaced matches.